# jquery ajax post method not work in iis7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, iis-7, http-post, kendo-grid

I have problem with ajax call in IIS 7 in MVC  , i use jquery ajax like this:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("IsLoanNumberValid", "File")',
      type: 'Post',
      cache: false,
      data: {   
            fileCategoryId: ddlFileCategory.value(),
        loanNumber: $("#txtLoanNumber").val(),
       }
   .....}
```

i don't have any problem when i develop application but when i publish mvc application and upload in iis post method have problem and do not return result ,

this is requests in firebug design time
[image: this is requests in firebug design time]

this is request when application is in iis7

[image]

all of ajax post method can not return result

also FilterFiles_Read method that Called by Kendo grid have problem in post method!
 grid binds by this line of code : **.Read(read => read.Action("FilterFiles_Read","File")**

this is its code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CommonData.Domain.File>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Pageable()
    .EnableCustomBinding(true) 
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
    columns.Bound(e => e.FileCategory.Title);
    columns.Bound(e => e.BankFileNo);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.Id))
    .Read(read => read.Action("FilterFiles_Read","File").Data("GetValues"))
    .PageSize(10)
        .Total(TempData["Total"] == null ? 0 : (int)TempData["Total"])
    )
)
```

Do i must configure iis or must change applicaion? please help me

Comment: have you tested it in a browser other than FF?

Comment: yes , in all of them there is this problem "The specified network name is no longer available"

Answer (score 0):

@zeinab kalanaki, Do you still have problem? The solution in following [ASP.Net MVC $.Ajax() function not working when hosted in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491823/asp-net-mvc-ajax-function-not-working-when-hosted-in-iis7) helped me fixed mine. Try amending your url to

```
url: '@Url.Action("IsLoanNumberValid", "File")/',
```

Notice the added '/' at the end. seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Suman , thanks for your reply,i'm wrong ,network setting causes this problem and app was ok , thanks a lot